Google cloud deploy: sqlMessage: "Access denied for user 'hapi-server'@'cloudsqlproxy~34.151.243.169' (using password: YES)",
I'm trying to deploy a simple application on Google Cloud, but this error is ocurring:
/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'hapi-server'@'cloudsqlproxy~34.151.243.169' (using password: YES)
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:123:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.connect (/app/build/database.js:19:16)
    at _callee$ (/app/build/server.js:36:24)
    at tryCatch (/app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:45:16)
    at Generator.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:133:17)
    at Generator.next (/app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:74:21)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
    at _next (/app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:22:9)
Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
    at Connection._handleProtocolError (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:423:8)
    at Protocol.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Protocol._delegateError (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:398:10)
    at Handshake.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:153:12)
    at Handshake.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Handshake.Sequence.end (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:78:12)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:125:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10) {
  code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
  errno: 1045,
  sqlMessage: "Access denied for user 'hapi-server'@'cloudsqlproxy~34.151.243.169' (using password: YES)",
  sqlState: '28000',
  fatal: true
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! buy-and-sell-backend@1.0.0 start: `node ./build/server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the buy-and-sell-backend@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2024-04-26T23_58_13_480Z-debug.log`

I have been searching everywhere, but can't find a solution, I believe that is related with proxy settings, but I can't solve it.
The project is public in GitHub: https://github.com/JardelGalvao/buy-and-sell
With MySQL Workbench, the access is normally possible.
Anyone could help me please?
